# image is not embeding in email in php

Tags: php, html-email

I am trying to embed the image to the html content of email in php but whenever the email sent it show me broken link of image there. Image is not embeding to the email here is the code

```
<?php
$to = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';
$subject = "Beautiful HTML Email using PHP by CodexWorld";

$htmlContent = '
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to CodexWorld</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Thanks you for joining with us!</h1>
        <table cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dashed #FB4314; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th><td>CodexWorld</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Email:</th><td>contact@codexworld.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Website:</th><td><a href="http://www.codexworld.com">www.codexworld.com</a></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>image:</th><td><img src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/email/1.png"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

// Set content-type header for sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: xxxx@xxxxx.com' . "\r\n"; 

// Send email
if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)):
    $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
else:
    $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
endif;
?>
```

Please guide me where is I am wrong

Comment: One way you could do it would be to use the base64 encoded data as the source rather than a url

Comment: do you have any example for that? @RamRaider

Comment: For example: `echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, " . base64_encode( file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/images/email.png') ) . "' />";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add image to php mail body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861891/how-to-add-image-to-php-mail-body)