# Include an image in email PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm experiencing an issue where only the text from body is appearing the image is coming through broken, does anyone see where I might be going wrong?

```
<?php
  require("php/PHPMailer.php");
  require("php/SMTP.php");

  if (isset($_GET['email'])) {

    $emailID = $_GET['email'];

    if($emailID = 1){
      $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
      $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

      $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
      $mail->Host = "";
      $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->Username = "";
      $mail->Password = "";
      $mail->SetFrom("");
      $mail->Subject = "Test";
      $mail->Body = '<html><body><p>My Image</p><img src="images/EmailHeader.png" width="75%"></body></html>';

      $mail->AddAddress("");

      if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      } 
      else {
          echo "Message has been sent";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: `if($emailID = 1){` !== `if($emailID == 1){` - one equal is *always* true. And you need a full path to the live image, or include it with the email.

Comment: add full url of the image

Comment: You can't use a relative path on your server for images in emails.   You can embed it with base64 or use the full URL, keep in mind, this is opened on the person's computer, not on your server.

Comment: `<img src="/images/EmailHeader.png" width="75%">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add image to php mail body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861891/how-to-add-image-to-php-mail-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image URL you are using is relative. You will need to use the **full URL**.

Instead of:

```
<img src="images/EmailHeader.png" width="75%">
```

It needs to be an absolute URL that the public can see, such as:

```
<img src="https://image-website.com/images/EmailHeader.png" width="75%">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload image with  `relative path` in Email. You have to use `full path` because **when the mail is send it require whole path to fetch the image content.**,

Replace this line,

```
  $mail->Body = '<html><body><p>My Image</p><img src="images/EmailHeader.png" width="75%"></body></html>';
```

With this line,

```
  $mail->Body = '<html><body><p>My Image</p><img src="http://your-domainname.com/images/EmailHeader.png" width="75%"></body></html>';
```

Another option is that you can use use `base64` images for it. But in your case you have to give full path.